# Oracle trigger to compare dates

Tags: oracle, date, triggers

So I am making an oracle database for a university coursework. My coursework is to make a database for an airlines.

The problem I am having is that I have to make sure that the passport expiry date on a new passenger record is not less than the current date (that is, make sure that the person's passport is still valid).

could someone please help me out with creating a trigger to do this? I have the entity PASSPORT_EXPIRY in table PASSPORT set to the datatype DATE.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming you can create the trigger..(?)

you will be comparing to `SYSDATE` - the built in holder for today (right now).

inside a trigger - you are allowed to write PL SQL.  so you can have IF checks.

your check will be something like

```
IF SYSDATE > PASSPORT_EXPIRY THEN
```

or you can probably write this into a select statement where you query maybe the days between now and expiry..

```
SELECT SYSDATE - PASSPORT_EXPIRY INTO diff
from PASSPORT WHERE ...
```

then check if diff < 0.. etc.